# Using interp2 to make number of points smaller

Tags: matlab, interpolation

This is what my code looks like now

```
b=load('filenamehere');
b=b(46:285,51:170);

x=1:size(b,1);
y=1:size(b,2);

xq=1:size(b,1)/4;
yq=1:size(b,2)/4;

B=interp2(x,y,b,xq,yq);
```

b is 240x120 matrix, and I'm trying to have it be a 60x30 matrix so that my computer can handle the later computations I have to make. not sure what I have to do to make it work, I've also tried using `[X,Y]=meshgrid(x,y)` and the same for xq, yq. any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see several problem in your code.

```
b=load('filenamehere');
```

will return a struct, rather than a matrix. Let's ignore this for now, and suppose you have matrix *b* with 240x120 size.

Your *xq* and *yq* take the first 1/4 of *b*. I guess you want to take one point from every four. If so, you can do

```
B = b(1:4:end, 1:4:end);
```

or use *downsample* if you have Signal processing toolbox:

```
B = downsample(b, 4);
```

If you really need interpolation, xq and yq, if they are vector, should have different orientations:

```
B = interp2(b, 1:4:120, (1:4:240).');
```

Comment: I see what you were saying, I use 'filenamehere' as a place holder, it is actually an .mfm file; the B = interp2(b, 1:4:120, (1:4:240).'); worked. Thank you, could you explain what it does, and mean?

Comment: That simply takes one point every 4 points. Make you that is good for you. The interp2 will do some smoothing though. Choose what best fits your need.